# Importing files without adding .js extension existing project

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, solidity

I am trying to try to add some BDD tests to this repo: https://github.com/rocket-pool/rocketpool

I've created a feature file in /test/features and a new steps file in /test/support.

The feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: Test

Scenario: Test Deposit Below The Minimum Amount
 When A Staker Tries to Deposit Below the Minimum Amount
 Then The Transaction Should Revert
```

The steps file complains about all the imports, which look like this :

```
import { printTitle } from '../_utils/formatting';
```

They do not include the .js extension. In order to get to this point (which I had to fight with using import vs require), I had to add `"type": "module"` to the package.json file, my run command looks like this `npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/test.feature --import test/support/*.js`

If I add the .js extension to the imports in my steps file, it will then complain about all the imports in other files in the project. I do not want to change all of them to use .js, and I would like to just be able to be able to keep the changes to a minimum. I have looked into webpack and babel, but there are several config files included in the node_modules for  these packages so I am not sure which ones to modify, or even if that will help me in this case. It appears I am in commonjs/esm hell and I have very little experience with JavaScript.

Edit: Tried this:

```
node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/*.feature --import test/support/*.js
```

Now get this error

Running command: node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/*.feature --import test/support/*.js --name "Test Deposit Below The Minimum Amount"
(node:7504) ExperimentalWarning: The Node.js specifier resolution flag is experimental. It could change or be removed at any time.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/errors:490
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/c:/Users/_***/git/rocketpool/npx' imported from c:\Users_***\git\rocketpool
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:308:15)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:838:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
at ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:525:22)
at node:internal/modules/run_main:58:28
at loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:91:11) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND
}

Node.js v18.16.0

> ERROR: Command exited with status code 1.`

Comment: Trying running nodeJs with the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag.

Comment: @Andy where in the project do I add that?

Comment: Try `NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-specifier-resolution=node" npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/test.feature --import test/support/*.js`.

Comment: @Andy that didnt work. I did get more progress with `node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/*.feature --import test/support/*.js` but that then gives me the error I added to the original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading "[CommonJS (cjs) and Modules (esm): Import compatibility](https://adamcoster.com/blog/commonjs-and-esm-importexport-compatibility-examples)" from [Adam Coster](https://github.com/adam-coster), in Node.js, there are two module systems: [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/modules.html) and [ECMAScript (ESM)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/esm.html).

- CommonJS is the traditional module system in Node.js where modules are imported using `require` and exported using `module.exports`.
- ESM is the newer standard, which uses `import` and `export` statements, and is what's used in modern JavaScript development.

When you add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`, you are telling Node.js to treat `.js` files as ESM by default.
Which could be an issue.

When using ESM, Node.js expects the full file path including the extension. While this can be tedious, it is part of the specification. You could write a script to automatically add the `.js` extension to all imports, but this could be risky if you are not familiar with the codebase.

So if you do not want to add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`, you can rename your ESM files to have a `.mjs` extension. This will tell Node.js that those specific files are using ESM syntax.

Or: You can remove `"type": "module"` from your `package.json` and instead rely on the [`esm` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm) which allows you to use `import` statements in Node.js without converting everything to ESM. You can install it by running `npm install esm`, and then you can require it in your test script like this:

```bash
node -r esm your-test-script.js
```

This might allow you to avoid modifying the existing codebase while still using `import` statements in your test files.

However, since you're using `npx` to execute Cucumber tests and not directly running a script with Node.js, you'll need to adapt this concept for use with `npx`:

```bash
set NODE_OPTIONS=-r esm
npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/*.feature --import test/support/*.js
```

The `-r esm` part tells Node.js to require the `esm` module, which allows you to use `import` statements in your scripts without converting everything to ECMAScript Modules (ESM).

Comment: So does the new command, also take into account the experimental flag in ```NODE_OPTIONS``` - or is that no longer required as the ```-r esm``` option is being passed as arguments, that handle the import statements - or are they doing the same thing ? If that is the case, then I like your method as it keeps it simple with just having to run the one command and not worrying about exporting the ```NODE_OPTIONS```

Comment: @djmonki Yes, my answer was expanding on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493510/importing-files-without-adding-js-extension-existing-project/76511052#comment134901180_76508644): try it first after exporting `NODE_OPTION`.

Comment: When you say to require `node -r esm your-test-script.js` in my test script where am I supposed to do that? I'm currently getting an error of `npx: the --n argument has been removed.`
See `npm help exec` `for more information
npm ERR! could not determine executable to run` when running the npx command

Comment: @user1984300 You are using npx, so the `node -r esm your-test-script.js` would not apply to you here. I have updated the npx command.

Comment: @VonC I'm on Windows, would I set the NODE_OPTIONS like this: `$env:NODE_OPTIONS="-r esm"`? I did it like that and got a strange error when running the npx command. There was a huge printout about esm.js and then I see this at the bottom `C:\Users\_\git\rocketpool\node_modules\yaml\dist\compose\composer.js:33
                if (prelude[i + 1]?.[0] !== '#')            SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)`

Comment: @user1984300 That is powershell. Try it first in a simple CMD.

Comment: @VonC still getting the same error. `echo %NODE_OPTIONS%` prints out `-r esm`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254169/discussion-between-user1984300-and-vonc).

Answer (score 2):

This exception `Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/c:/Users/_/git/rocketpool/npx'` is being returned, because the `npx` command is being interpreted as a module name, hence the `ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND`.

### NODE_OPTIONS

Set the `NODE_OPTIONS` environment variable with the `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node` flag to enable the experimental specifier resolution feature

```js
export NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-specifier-resolution=node"
```

Setting `NODE_OPTIONS` this way, will ensure Node.js uses the experimental specifier for all subsequent executions in the same terminal session

### Cucumber Command

Then run the Cucumber command separately:

```bash
npx @cucumber/cucumber test/features/*.feature --import test/support/*.js
```

### This is a breakdown of the cucumber command:

1. **npx** - package runner tool, which will take the NODE_OPTIONS to determine the flag to run experimental...
2. **@cucumber/cucumber** - providing cucumber package name to `npx`, so it locate the installed version from `node_modules` dir
3. **test/features/*.feature** - path to your feature files with the `.feature` extn
4. **--import test/support/*.js** - path to your step definition files that have the `.js` extn

Combining all the above, should allow the `experimental-specifier-resolution` to import the JavaScript files without the .js extension

***Remember, if you open a new terminal session, you'll need to set NODE_OPTIONS again.***

Comment: This has gotten me past that hurdle (I set node options on windows like this: `$env:NODE_OPTIONS="--experimental-specifier-resolution=node"`) but now I get this error: ReferenceError: artifacts is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/_/git/rocketpool/test/_utils/artifacts.js:1:37
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25). If I remove the `"type": "module"` from the package.json file then I get the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

Comment: I've since tried to rename my deposit-pool-steps.js file to a .mjs extension, removed the `"type": "module"` from package.json, renamed all my import to look like : `import pkgPrintTitle from '../_utils/formatting';
const { printTitle } = pkgPrintTitle;`, and now I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`.

Comment: Take note of @VonC answer below, this is very important and you have to stick to a process and keep consistent.